# How to join multiple table with multiple where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6

My purpose is to get all users who has a relation to `school_admin` or `dormitory_admin`

So here are the tables.

```
users (has one school_admin or has one dormitory_admin)
-id
-username

has_one :school_admin
has_one :dormitory_admin

school_admins (pivot table)
-id
-school_id
-user_id

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :school

dormitory_admins (pivot table)
-id
-dormitory_id
-user_id

school (has many dormitory)
-id
-name

has_many :dormitories

dormitory (belongs to one school)
-id
-school_id
```

Here is my current query (I have 2 queries now which I need to merge it to be one query)

```
@q1 = User.joins(:school_admin).where(school_admin: { school_id: current_user.school_admin.school_id }).select("users.id, users.username, school_admin.name, school_admin.phone").ransack(params[:q])
@q2 = User.joins(:dormitory_admin).where(dormitory_admin: { dormitory_id: current_user.school_admin.school.dormitories.pluck(:id) }).select("users.id, users.username, dormitory_admin.name, dormitory_admin.phone").ransack(params[:q])
```

I am using ransack gem for table filtering and PostgreSQL for the database.

I can do "UNION" using pure SQL like `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)`, but if I use it, the ransack gem won't work.

Comment: Can you add the association

Comment: updated, sir check my new updated post

Comment: @mrobbizulifkar Check now I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of to_sql on an existing scope and then stick it in the from clause

```
 query1 =  User.joins(:school_admin).where(school_admin: current_user.school_admin).select("users.id, users.username, school_admins.name, school_admins.phone")
    
 query2 = User.joins(:dormitory_admin).where(dormitory_admin: current_user.dormitory_admin).select("users.id, users.username, dormitory_admins.name, dormitory_admins.phone")
    
    
 User.from("(#{query1.to_sql} UNION #{query2.to_sql}) AS users").ransack(params[:q])
    
    
    SELECT "users".* FROM (
        SELECT 
        users.id, 
        users.username, 
        school_admins.name, 
        school_admins.phone 
        FROM "users" 
        INNER JOIN "school_admins" 
        ON "school_admins"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
        WHERE "users"."id" = 1 
        UNION 
        SELECT 
        users.id, 
        users.username, 
        dormitory_admins.name, 
        dormitory_admins.phone 
        FROM "users" 
        INNER JOIN "dormitory_admins" 
        ON "dormitory_admins"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
        WHERE "users"."id" = 2) 
    AS users;
```

Or a better way will be which will avoid duplicate query

```
User.from("(#{User.joins(:school_admin).where(school_admin: current_user.school_admin).select("users.id, users.username, school_admins.name, school_admins.phone").to_sql} UNION #{User.joins(:dormitory_admin).where(dormitory_admin: current_user.dormitory_admin).select("users.id, users.username, dormitory_admins.name, dormitory_admins.phone").to_sql}) AS users").ransack(params[:q])
```

**Note:** The table name I have used are plural **school_admins** & **dormitory_admins**. Also, I have modified the where clause in the query1 & query2